# Dimension of state space

Tags: c-star-algebras

Let A be a $\mathcal{C}$* algebra. We define  state , say  $\phi$ on A  ( linear functional on A) such that f is positive and $\phi$( 1)= 1 .

I'm trying to prove the following :
If A is isomorphic to C iff order of state space is 1.

The usual part is trivial as if A is isomorphic then there is only one map , the identity function.

But how to I conclude the converse part? . As $\mathbb{C}$ is multiplicative , from there does it follow that state is homomorphism ? & What should I do to show its injective?

Comment: What do you mean by the "order" of the state space?

Comment: Additionally, please use proper [mathjax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Here order means the  total number of state defined on the C* algebra

Comment: Sorry  it's off topic but I still do not understand how to use mathjax . To write blackboard bold I have to use \mathbb , but how ?  I'm using a android and it's not showing feasible result .

Comment: Follow the link in my previous comment to get started on learning $\LaTeX$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there exists only one state $\varphi$ on the unital $C^*$-algebra $A$.  Then $\varphi$ must be faithful.  If not, then there is some nonzero positive element $a\in A$ with $\varphi(a)=0$.  But every positive element achieves its norm by some state, a contradiction.

If now $a\in A$ is positive, $\|a\|=1$, then $\varphi(a)=1$, so $\varphi(1-a)=0$ and thus $a=1$.  Thus every positive element is of the form $\lambda\cdot1$ for some $\lambda\in[0,\infty)$.  Now every element of $A$ is in the span of the positive elements, hence lies in the span of $1$, and therefore $A=\mathbb C\cdot 1\cong\mathbb C$.

Comment: I understood it. Then from this fact can I conclude that there's always exists a non trivial unitary  element in a unital  $\mathcal{C}$* algebra other than $\mathbb{C}$ .

Comment: And there always exists a non trivial self adjoint element in a $\mathcal{C}$* algebra other than $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Yes, if $A$ is a unital $C^*$-algebra, and every self-adjoint element is of the form $\lambda1$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb R$, then $A\cong\mathbb C$.